# Root finding inaccurate in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to solve a root finding problem in Python that should be pretty easy but so far has proven to be a tough nut. I've rendered the equations below as a function:

```
def fullsol(x, DIC, QCharge):

return [x[3] - (DIC/((1 +(K1/x[0]) + (K1*K2/(x[0])**2)))), 
        x[1] - (DIC/((1 +(x[0]/K1) + (K2/(x[0]))))), 
        x[2] - (DIC/(1 +(x[0]/K2) + ((x[0]**2)/K1*K2))),
        (x[0]*x[4]) - Kw,
        2*QCharge - x[0] + x[1] + 2*x[2] + x[4] - (DIC/0.78)]
```

This function returns 5 equations with 5 unknowns ("DIC" and "QCharge" are constants), and I next call a least squares optimization (from scipy) to get the root, with an initial guess and bounds (I know all parameters are greater than zero):

```
x0 = ([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

solution = optimize.least_squares(fullsol, x0, args=(0.0035, 0),bounds =(0,np.inf))
```

When I run this code, I get a result I KNOW is wrong, because running the exact problem in Mathematica (using NSolve) gives a different, and much more accurate, answer. I get the same (wrong) answer in Python when I use `optimize.root` instead of least squares, so it's almost as if Python's optimization packages are just...inaccurate.

I'd appreciate any guidance on whether or not I'm doing something wrong, advice for troubleshooting and/or what the closest approximation of NSolve would be in Python.

PS. I tried using NSolve in Python, but it couldn't find the root within the given tolerance. Code below:

```
K1 = 10**-5.86
K2 = 10**-8.92
Kw = 10**-13.22
DIC = 0.0035
QCharge = 0

x0 = Symbol('x0')
x1 = Symbol('x1')
x2 = Symbol('x2')
x3 = Symbol('x3')
x4 = Symbol('x4')

f1 = x3 - DIC/((1 +(K1/x0) + (K1*K2/(x0)**2)))
f2 = x1 - DIC/((1 +(x0/K1) + (K2/(x0))))
f3 = x2 - DIC/(1 +(x0/K2) + ((x0**2)/K1*K2))
f4 = x0*x4 - Kw
f5 = -x0+ 2*QCharge + x1 + 2*x2+ x4 - (DIC/0.78)

solution = nsolve((f1,f2,f3,f4,f5),(x0,x1,x2,x3,x4),(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))
```

Comment: Almost certainly the limitations of floating point arithmetic,  but can you elaborate?

Comment: Both optimize.root and optimize.least_squares give me a solution in which x[0]*x[4], for instance, is several orders of magnitude off from Kw (which is 10^-14): I end up getting something like 10^-6 for that product (in case you're familiar with chemistry, Kw is the self-ionization constant of water, and needs to be close to 10^-14 for my model to reflect reality....). K1 is 10^-5.86 and K2 is 10^-0.92. Can you say any more about floating point arithmetic and how I can get around this? Thanks

Comment: Can you just use [nsolve](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve) in Python ?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I get the error "ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance (6.21975346313850940634e-12 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19). Try another starting point or tweak arguments." The other thing about NSolve in Python is that I can't specify that the solution be positive